# bound on covariant derivative of second fundemantal form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I'm trying to read the paper ([Schoen-Simon-Yau '74](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485889848)) and can't figure out one of the bounds they use on the derivative of the second fundamental form.

In detail: Let $M$ a minimal hypersurface embedded in an $n$+1 dimensional Riemannian manifold $N$. It follows $$h_{ijk} = \nabla_k h_{ij} = -\frac 12 \, K_{n+1,ijk},$$ where $h_{ij}$ is the second fundamental form of $M$, $\nabla$ is the induced connection on $M$ and $K$ is the Riemann tensor on $N$. Let the sectional curvatures of $N$ be bounded between $K_1$ and $K_2$.

In the paper, before eq. (1.28) they introduce the inequality $$|K_{n+1,iji}| \leq \frac 12 (K_1 - K_2). \qquad (*)$$

How do I see this result?

I tried to use that $\sum_i h_{ii} = 0$, $\sum_i h_{iik} = 0$, and $(*)$ but that lead to nowhere.

Maybe someone has a tip? I would be very grateful!

Comment: How do you get  $\nabla_k h_{ij} = -\frac 12 \, K_{n+1,ijk}$? For the usual Codazzi equation, you get control on only $\nabla_k h_{ij} - \nabla_ih_{kj}$.

Comment: this is obtained by exterior differentiating  $\omega_{n+1,i} = h_{ij} \, \omega_j$ (ie. cartan's lemma, since on $M$ we have $0 = \omega_{n+1} = \mathrm d \omega_{n+1}$) and using the first structure equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that they are off by a factor of $2$.

Let $j\neq i$ (or the inequality is trivial), write 
$$e = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (e_{n+1} + e_j).$$
Note $e$ is a unit vector and is orthogonal to $e_i$. Then

\begin{align*}
2K_{n+1, iji} &= 2K(e_{n+1}, e_i, e_j, e_i) \\
&= K(e_{n+1}+e_j, e_i, e_{n+1} + e_j, e_i) - K(e_{n+1}, e_i, e_{n+1}, e_i) - K(e_j, e_i, e_j, e_i) \\
&= 2K(e, e_i, e, e_i) - K(e_{n+1}, e_i, e_{n+1}, e_i) - K(e_j, e_i, e_j, e_i) \\
&\le 2K_1 - 2K_2. 
\end{align*}

From (1.24) in the paper, it seems that they assume $K_2 \le K_{ijij} \le K_1$. Since the inequality depends solely on $N$ but not on the minimal submanifolds $M$, I don't think the equation on $h$ helpes. On the other hand, the constant $2$ is not crucial in their calculations. You can absorb it into the $\epsilon$ for example.

Comment: i tend to think too complicated! thanks a lot!